# minikube start fails - no such user

Tags: virtualbox, minikube

I try to start Minikube, but keep getting this error (tried VirtualBox and hyperkit):

```
✨  Preparing Kubernetes environment ...
  Downloading kubeadm v1.13.4
  Downloading kubelet v1.13.4
  Failed to setup kubeconfig: writing kubeconfig: Error recursively changing ownership for dir: /Users/myusername/.kube: Error looking up user: user: unknown user myusername
  Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new
find: -user: retacc: no such user
```

retacc is the admin user of another VM I have mounted in VirtualBox. But I don't know how the connections happens. Tried deleting and reinstalling kubectl/minikube.

Comment: Hi, what is `kubectl version` ? Does **/Users/retacc/.kube** really exist?

Comment: Hi, no, retacc is not my username, so .kube is under /Users/<username>/.kube. Can I change that somehow?

Comment: Which OS do you run? Kubectl version?

Comment: no it doesn't. It exists under /Users/<username>/.kube --> I am not sure why "retacc" is chosen, it is no user under my mac (only in a VM). Can I change the user?

Comment: sorry, I got lost, where do you try to run minikube? on VM or on your mac?